# Pushforward of Coherent Sheaf Along Projective Morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is Vakil 18.1 A, self-study, and intended to be a consequence of the basic properties of the cohomology of quasi-coherent sheaves.

We are to show that if $\pi: X \to Y$ is projective, and $\mathcal F$ is coherent on $X$, then $\pi_*\mathcal F$ is coherent on $Y$ (if $X$ and $Y$ are locally Noetherian). We do not yet know this holds for proper morphisms, so we cannot use that.

Facts we know that seem relevant (in fact, this was proven almost immediately before this exercise): If $\mathcal F$ is coherent on a projective $A$-scheme $X$, with $A$ Noetherian, then $H^i(X, \mathcal F)$ is a coherent $A$-module for all $i$. In particular, $\mathcal F(X)$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module.

My best attempt so far is to factor $\pi$ through some $\mathbb P \mathcal E \to Y$ via closed immersion $X \hookrightarrow \mathbb P \mathcal E$, and use the fact that the composition of pushforwards is the pushforward of the composition, but I do not see how this gives us the result.

Comment: Hint: think more locally on $Y$. Can you reduce to the case when $Y=\operatorname{Spec} A$? Do you see how this might help you use your relevant fact?

Comment: I agree the problem is affine local on the target. And I have now successfully shown the problem without using cohomology. The problem is that I believe Vakil wishes for a simpler cohomologocal proof, because the rest of the results in the section essentially follow from this result (without cohomology, I might add).

Comment: This is a one-liner once you know your relevant fact, which is a part of a cohomological statement. Seems pretty simple and cohomological to me!

Comment: Do you mean the relevant fact I shared? Don't we need its converse to be true to show something is coherent?

Comment: Work affine-locally on $Y$, so $Y=\operatorname{Spec} A$. Then $\pi_*\mathcal{F} = \widetilde{\mathcal{F}(X)}$, which is coherent because it's the sheaf associated to a coherent $A$-module.

Comment: Why is the pushforward sheaf the sheaf associated to $\mathcal F(X)$?

Comment: It's a quasi-coherent sheaf (by theorem 16.2.1) on an affine scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me recap the solution developed in the comments. Start by reducing to the case where $Y=\operatorname{Spec} A$ is the spectrum of a noetherian ring. By Vakil's theorem 16.2.1, the pushforward of the quasicoherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ along a projective morphism $\pi:X\to Y$ is quasicoherent on $Y$. This means it's the sheaf associated to $(\pi_*\mathcal{F})(Y)=\mathcal{F}(X)$, which by corollary 18.1.5 is coherent. As the sheaf associated to a coherent module is coherent, we are done.